# How do you tell the difference visually between a credit/debit card and a prepaid card?

Tags: united-states

My job is trying to do away with prepaid cards.  I however have been having trouble telling them apart from regualar credit cards.  How can you tell without running a credit check and ext.

Comment: Usually, a pre-paid card won’t have a cardholder name printed on it but a regular debit or credit card will.

Comment: Curious why? Why wouldn't you want to accept prepaid cards?

Comment: @gnasher729 It may be a car hire company or hotel or other business that relies on being able to add excess charges onto the card used for payment. You can’t do that with a prepaid card that’s not got much money left on it.

Comment: And that's exactly why prepaid cards are so good under the right circumstances.

Comment: @MikeScott: but wouldn't the same thing be true with a debit card where there isn't much money left on the checking account? or a credit card with a low limit?

Comment: CC have numbers and holder name pressed/convex (more costly process) while prepaid have it laser engraved/concave

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY: Then how do I have in my hand an Amex Serve prepaid card with raised numbers and name and a Discover credit card where they are flat (not even engraved)?  The production processes are up to the issuer; there are no universal rules.

Answer (score 1):

The two pieces of information are different:

- The name of the person on the front of a prepaid card is usually 'Thank You'
- The back of the card usually mentions 'monthly maintenance fees'

Calling the number on the back of the card is also a way to verify both the type of card as well as the identifying information associated with it.

Comment: But my name really is "Valued Cardholder"

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: It may be possible to find this information using an online lookup tool (although, as noted in a comment, the specific tool I found may not be very accurate or up-to-date).

The first six digits of a credit/debit card number are the ***Issuer Identification Number*** (**IIN**) – see [Payment card number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_card_number) on Wikipedia. The IIN can potentially tell you a lot about the card beyond who issued it: for example, whether it is a debit or credit card, and whether it is prepaid or not. The "master list" of IINs is maintained by the [American Bankers Association](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Bankers_Association).

The blog-post ["Is There a Way to Tell If a Card Number Is Debit or Credit?"](https://millionmilesecrets.com/guides/is-there-a-way-to-tell-if-a-card-number-is-debit-or-credit/) covers some of the information that can be gleaned from the IIN using the free service [Binlist.net](https://binlist.net/), including its type and prepaid status. Note, however, that the blog's "bottom line" includes:

> Binlist also works to tell if a card is a prepaid debit gift card, but it’s not as consistent at providing [this] information [*as indicating whether it is a debit/credit card*].

Also note the Binlist site's disclaimer:

> Although this service is very accurate, don't expect it to be perfect.

---

*Disclaimer*: I am not affiliated with either the blog site the above link is taken from, or the Binlist site, nor can I vouch for their accuracy.

Comment: I just tried 6 US cards on Binlist and 4 were wrong in some way. It even claimed a debit card was credit. Their data Github shows no updates for 2 years. Perhaps a paid service would be more accurate.

Comment: @user71659 Thanks for your comment. I only had a couple of UK cards and it was correct on those. I've added a cautionary note to the top of my answer.